# Building libftdi library issue: not finding the 'libusb-1.0' package

Tags: linux

The libftdi library depends on the libusb library.  I installed the libusb library. Inside /usr/local/lib i see libusb-1.0.a and libusb-1.0.dylib

However when I try to build libftdi it complains of

```
-- Found PkgConfig: /opt/local/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.28") 
-- checking for module 'libusb-1.0'
--   package 'libusb-1.0' not found
-- Could NOT find LIBUSB (missing:  LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Comment: It generally helps if you show that you've tried to diagnose your problem rather than just asking StackOverflow to diagnose it for you.  Reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might give you some ideas.

Comment: Fix capitalization and other style

Comment: Fix capitalization and other style issues and add detail to the title.